# What happened to Ralph's game while he was inside the Internet?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph

In "Ralph Breaks the Internet", the characters are depicted as being a part of an arcade game within an arcade, and during out of hours time they live a secret life behind a power-board where they hop between the different games in the arcade as if they were properties.

When Vanellope's game breaks, the game is almost immediately unplugged leaving all the characters essentially homeless. Ralph decides to sneak into the wireless router that has recently been plugged into the power-board, and several times he clearly states that there are numerous days before Vanellope's game is to be scrapped in which they have to find the elusive part that will fix her arcade game.

My question is what happened to Ralph's game during the time he was inside the Internet? Was his game in danger of being scrapped aswell? It seems like a strange plot hole that he has freedom to do stuff without consequence, while everyone else has to put in their shift.

Comment: What evidence supports the fact that Ralph was gone from his game longer than overnight? Seems to me that everything could have been accomplished between the evening closing of Litwak's Family Fun Center and Arcade and the next morning's opening.

Comment: What *could* have happened to it? IIRC the stick broke or something, so it's not like everyone came around wondering why they can't see Ralph in a game they weren't playing.

Comment: @Jeeped. They made the bids on the steering wheel and won the auction. They were then told they had 24 hours to come up with the money for the steering wheel. Eboy warns Ralph he has just 30 minutes left of the 24 hour period to pay for the item. So they were gone for at least 23.5 hours, which means the arcade would've had a full day with Ralph inexplicably missing from his game.

Comment: My bad. I just rewatched the film and there was only 8 hours left when Ralph started making viral videos.

Comment: Well, the same thing as in the first movie could have happend. If I remember correctly, the machine was labeled as broken with some sticker, but when a guy came to fix it, Ralph has returned and everything was working again?

Comment: Maybe the arcade was closed on the day they were gone? I mean, a lot of ebay auctions are set to end on a Sunday because people will have time/be at home then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix-It Felix says something along the lines of:

> I'll cover for you

We can only speculate that it's a mix of Felix covering for Ralph and the game not being as popular as it once was.

Plus as few people have pointed out in the comments, it could have been a day when the arcade was closed, we know it all happened in roughly the space of 24-36 hours, which isn't that long.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, *Fix-It Felix Jr.* (Ralph's game) was not the most popular game at the arcade and Ralph's absence was not even noticed *sad trombone*

Consider the age of the game by the graphics and gameplay depicted.  Similar to *Donkey Kong* or the original *Mario Bros*, this looks like an 80's game that somehow has survived to modern era.

Compare to *Sugar Rush* which looks like a modern racing game, with up to date graphics and steering wheel controls (as opposed to a joystick and button pad).

Had a patron noticed that the *Fix-It Felix Jr.* game was missing its antagonist, they likely would have notified Mr Litwak who would have done as he did in the original film, taped off the cabinet and schedule it for disconnection.

However, as we saw *Calhoun* and *Felix* live a harmonious life with the kids from *Sugar Rush* (kidding), we can assume that either the entirety of the movie ocurred while the arcade was closed or that no one tried to play the game while Ralph was missing.